# Breaking single thread

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to break a single thread in Visual Studio, while other threads will continue their execution?

I have one background thread that does simple data sending/receiving, which I would like to happen, while stepping through my code in some other thread.

Comment: +1 good question. Would like to know myself...

Comment: Disclaimer :-) haven't checked documentation, but the way it behaves (VS 2008 certainly) is that a break will halt all threads in the process, and each time you step, all threads will be given the chance to resume until the end of the step. You then select which thread you want to step through.

Comment: Kev, I suppose you're right. Wonder what could be the reason for not implementing this scenario...

Comment: I think implementing this would be extremely hard due to possible synchronization issues.

Comment: It is possible to wake up threads using debug evaluation (like QuickWatch, or add watch) by calling ResumeThread on the ones you want to keep running.  However, Visual Studio will get really confused if you unsuspend a thread that it suspended.  It does, however, make it possible to unsuspend a thread, wait for it to do something, and then suspend it back, before returning control to the Visual Studio debugger.  Not globally useful, but useful for certain scenarios.

Answer (score 12):

open the thread view (Debug->Windows->Threads), right-click the thread you want to suspend, select 'Freeze'. Select 'Thaw' to put it back in a running state.

Comment: Thread window is inactive while the program is running. And 'Thaw' does not really put it into running state, it just means that this thread will run (among others) after I'll release a program from breakpoint. What I want to do is to step through one thread, while others run in background.

Comment: I see. As others pointed out, don't think that can be done in the IDE. You could simultae it by pulling out that thread from the code and running it as a seperate process. Not easy though if it has to communicate a lot with the other threads. Your best bet is extensive logging.

Answer (score 8):

Generally it's impossible, but there are some things that might work for specific scenarios.

**Basic solution**
As mentioned elsewhere, repeating the sequence: *Freeze, Resume, (wait), Pause, Thaw, Step*  should result in the behavior you describe, giving other threads the possibility of running in the background while your target thread is halted.

This approach has at least two issues:

- It's quite tedious
- Your background threads will be suspended anytime the debugger is paused.

**Improvements**

The first issue may be tackled using a different procedure: Issue a `Thread.Sleep(10000)` in the Immediate Window, effectively keeping the focused thread occupied while the other threads execute normally. You could even bind that command to a macro.

The second issue can only be tackled by an approach that does not need to pause the debugger. But how would we examine state when the session isn't paused? That's where [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) comes in, but you may find you need to create [custom IntelliTrace events](http://blog.qetza.net/en/2010/03/08/vs-2010-personnalisation-des-vnements-de-lintellitrace/). Drawback of this approach is that you can not manually modify state mid-flight.

Comment: Not the best, but I just added `Thread.Sleep(10000)` to my code (temporarily).  Got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Set a counter that does a one up for each thread created and then set your break point to break on a condition and pick a value for that counter.  I don't think this will work in all cases, especially PLINQ, but should be doable in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 0):

All i can find to this, is that you can change the behaviour on a process level [by the setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx)

- Tools - Options - Debugging - General - Break all processes when one process breaks

but not on a Thread base.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put a conditional break point based on a property of your current thread (like the name or id).

You may also find this usefull : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/396617/Conditional-Breakpoint-using-Make-Object-Id-featur

This worked for me in VS2008 and should work in a similar way in 2010 at the least