# Is it possible to break all threads but one in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, ide, breakpoints

Is it possible to break all threads but one in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

One of the threads in my application is running a TCP proxy. The server that it connects to disconnects when the client (that connects to my proxy) doesn't send a keep-alive packet every few seconds.

So I would need to break all other threads (like packet processing) so that I can edit that part without getting disconnected.

Is this achievable without add-ons?

Comment: It sounds like you want to perform surgery on an active patient.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, we are in a world with local anesthesia, aren't we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution that might possibly work, is to write a macro that you call when you stop at a BP that function evaluates some function that sends some stay alive packets.

E.g. your macro goes like

DTE.Windows.Item("{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}").Activate() 'Immediate Window
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Print", "KeepAliveFunc()")

It's obviously not ideal, but if nothing else helps...

Comment: This actually isn't a bad idea. Not really a direct answer but it should work, so accepting.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is not possible. See [Breaking single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422875/breaking-single-thread) for a previous discussion of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you Break All in the debugger, in the threads window, right click on all of the threads you don't want to run and select freeze, then continue running, only your target thread will be running.

Comment: Not exactly: "So I would need to break all other threads so that I can *edit* that part without getting disconnected." You can't edit your code when the application is running.

Comment: @lesderid Actually you can.  Aside from the fact that you can use the debugger to change values, the [edit and continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) feature allows you to modify the code, re-compile and update the application while it's running.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to just put a while loop in the thread that are you wanting to pause with a timer to output data about certain variables on a textbox. Then make the button to step between the loops?

Just an idea.